# Ubuntu 22.04 got messed after some software upgrades

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, troubleshooting

Moments ago I upgraded some packages in my Ubuntu 22.04 (the software updater asked me to upgrade some packages and I said yes).

I noticed that oddly some of the packages in the software updater were unselected. Most of these packages were from NVIDIA. After the packages got upgraded, the updater window kept appearing asking for more upgrades. I tried to keep installing the upgrades, but the window kept appearing.

After getting tired from installing the updates, I decided to run an "apt upgrade" and an "apt autoremove". After that I decided, myself, to reboot the notebook since it was been a while since I didn't reboot it.

When the system got up and running again, I noticed that my network settings is now gone (wifi and wired), the touchpad is not working anymore, my Nvidia driver is not working, and I can't reduce/increase the brightness of the screen, and I have no sound from the speakers.

Looks like all the drivers got lost.

Can anyone help me? I am totally lost with this problem that came from nowhere.

I think I will probably reinstall ubuntu, it will be faster and easier, but I still don't know how this happened, how do I prevent it from happening again?

Here is a picture of the packages appearing in the software updater now:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are right, I forgot to mention that I ran i apt auto remove after apt upgrade. I will modify my question. How do I modify to troubleshooting advice? In the tags?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason the drivers got uninstalled.

I re-installed my Ubuntu, and the first thing I did after booting for the firs time was to use the `Software Updater` and upgrade some packages. Then I opened a terminal and typed `apt upgrade` and and I saw this:
[image]

Looks like the drivers are listed here, right?
Probable those packages got uninstalled when I typed `apt autoremove` in the previous system.
The question that remains open is: Why these packages are listed to be no longer required???? I thought that `apt autoremove` was a safe command.

Does anyone now how to explain this to me or another person with the same issue?